# Getting error 1054 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I found out. It was a spelling mistake. I misspelled  'manu_name' in Second table. Thank GUYS

Comment: Error explain itself, 'menu_name' field is not in your table.

Comment: Does your table have a column named `menu_name` in it? Probably not.

Comment: Can you post your table schema?(SHOW CREATE TABLE pages)

Comment: Sure I can. I will post my table schema in 5 minutes, let me type it. Thanks, guys

Comment: I found out. It was a spelling mistake. I misspelled 'manu_name' in Second table. Thanks GUYS

Answer (score 0):

Column   `menu_name` does not exist in table `pages`. Might be a spelling mistake or `missing quotes.`

Comment: You are right, It was a spelling mistake. I misspelled 'manu_name' in the second row of the second table. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in query. because the column as mention in the error not exists in your table. so create new column with this name or change the exact name that you have in your table.